# Find equation for hyperbola ($e=\sqrt 2$)

Tags: geometry

Say we have $P=(1,1)\in\mathbb R^2$ and $l\subset\mathbb R^2$ given by $y=-x$. I have to give the equation for the hyperbola with $P$ as focal point, $l$ as directrix, and $e=\sqrt 2$. So let $S=(x,y)$ be a point on the hyperbola. I am using $d(P,s)=e\cdot d(l,S)$.

I calculated $d(P,s)$ by considering the norm of the orthogonal projection of $S$ onto $(1,-1)$. This turned out to be $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt 2\vert x+y\vert$. But now I’m left with the following equation, and I’m not sure if this is right, because I don't think I should have have $xy$ terms;
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sqrt 2\vert x+y\vert=\sqrt 2\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}\\
\frac{1}{4}(x+y)^2=(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2\\
(x+y)^2=4(x^2+1-2x)+4(y^2+1-2y).
$$

*Edit*: I 'solved' it. The eccentricity $e=\sqrt 2$ should have been on the left side. This gives us:
$$
\sqrt 2\cdot\frac{1}{2}\sqrt 2\vert x+y\vert=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2}\\
(x+y)^2=(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2\\
2xy=-2x-2y+2
$$